# Do earned upgrades affect party members in Nimble Quest?

Tags: nimble-quest

The buffs specifically say that they apply to all party members.

Let's say I've earned the 25% Attack Rate bonus on Ulrich, but I choose Bones as my party leader. Will Ulrich still have his Attack Rate bonus applied, or do the earned bonuses only apply to the selected leader?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they do, according to Nimblebit. 
http://support.nimblebit.com/customer/portal/articles/1074299-upgrading-heroes

Comment: I believe the hero retains **his/her personal buffs**, when not leader.  For the personal buffs, I don't believe those apply to the whole party.  Pickup buffs on the other hand, do.